# How to get regular expression for the msg=" "

Tags: regex

```
<form id="lrMemberDashboard" action="/cboss/preRegistrationWorkflow/viewLRMemberDashboard?msg=Task%20has%20been%20successfully%20Accepted&amp;isRejected=false" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

How to get in MSG in a variable for the uper string:

```
msg=Task%20has%20been%20successfully%20Accepted
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, please consider [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 3):

In this case, for this input (and others similar to it), `msg=[^&"]+` will do. Beware, however, that parsing HTML with Regex only works reliably for well defined input.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what characters are allowed in the msg... https://regex101.com/r/W31NOb/1

```
msg=([^&]+)
```